# How mass rename files using find + grep + sed + xargs or in another way

Tags: linux

I use `find . -type f | grep " | "` and catch:

```
./java notes | multithreading.txt
./deep/java notes | deep.txt
./deep/java notes | common.txt
./java notes | xml.txt
./java notes | keywords
./sql/java notes | sql
./EE/java notes | spring.txt
./EE/java notes | ws.txt
./EE/java notes | jstl.txt
./EE/java notes | jsp.txt
./java notes | net.txt
./java notes | exceptions.txt
./java notes | common.txt
./linux/linux | different. txt
```

After this i do `find . -type f | grep " | " | sed "s/ | /_/"` and catch:

```
./java notes_multithreading.txt
./deep/java notes_deep.txt
./deep/java notes_common.txt
./java notes_xml.txt
./java notes_keywords
./sql/java notes_sql
./EE/java notes_spring.txt
./EE/java notes_ws.txt
./EE/java notes_jstl.txt
./EE/java notes_jsp.txt
./java notes_net.txt
./java notes_exceptions.txt
./java notes_common.txt
./linux/linux_different. txt
```

i would like to append `xargs` to rename all this files like made `sed` command. Or maybe there are another ways to resolve it? How i could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop in bash, like this:

```
for file in "$(find . -type f | grep " | ")"
do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed "s/ | /_/")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line using the perl rename function:

```
    $ rename -v 's/\ \|\ /_/' *
    > test | 123.txt renamed as test_123.txt
```